# Why does this tensor has dtype attribute twice

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I just noticed this weird tensor:

```
Out[124]: <tf.Tensor: id=7672038, shape=(1,), dtype=uint8, numpy=array([1], dtype=uint8)>
```

It has dtype twice. Usually, you cannot get that. For instance,

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1]))
Out[126]: <tf.Tensor: id=7672042, shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1])>
```

Why is that, and what's the difference?

I just noticed this: the latter can be used as an index for a tensor, but the the former can't. It throws this error:

> TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis
>   (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 1

It is a stupid error, cause it says "got 1", and 1 is a legitimate index ! cause it is an integer for crying out loud! see the dtype above.

Comment: Maybe you should add some context for where you got this "weird tensor" from.

Comment: @xdurch0 I got it from tf.dataset.from_tensor_slices 
I fed it with numpy array

Answer (score 0):

It has not dtype twice, the seconde dtype, is for the numpy array.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But still, it is weird. It is as if there is a numpy OBJECT inside a tensor!  It should just be a tensor object that has a numpy value.

Comment: @AlexDeft "It is as if there is a numpy OBJECT inside a tensor!" well, that's how eager execution works.

Comment: @cs95 Okay, but still, I don't see the answer. Please see the updated question.